# Como converter uma array de bytes para uma imagem bitmap?

Tags: java, android, imageview, bitmap

Olá, estou tentando retornar para um ImageView uma imagem armazenada no banco de dados que está salva como uma array de bytes em um campo do tipo BLOB, qual seriam as alternativas par isto?

Answer (score 1):

Depois de buscar a imagem no banco de dados e salvar na variável array, você pode converter para Bitmap dessa forma:

```
    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
```

Caso o método não consiga fazer a conversão, vai retornar nulo.